# Cannot create weak reference to 'Weakcallableproxy' object in Pytorch Module

Tags: python, pytorch, garbage-collection, nvidia-docker

When i run my project in my system it was running fine, but when i made it as nvidia-docker2 container and run it i am getting the following error :

I ensured my pytorch version, cuda version are almost same in both the environments, whereas python version differs , 3.10 in my system, 3.8 in the docker container

Docker container Details :

```
➜ Face-Recognition-From-Crowd ⚡ 3 hours ago ( master)▶ sudo docker run --gpus all --device /dev/video0 --ipc=host --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 -it face-crowd bash

=============
== PyTorch ==
=============

NVIDIA Release 22.11 (build 48503342)
PyTorch Version 1.13.0a0+936e930

Container image Copyright (c) 2022, NVIDIA CORPORATION & AFFILIATES. All rights reserved.

Copyright (c) 2014-2022 Facebook Inc.
Copyright (c) 2011-2014 Idiap Research Institute (Ronan Collobert)
Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Deepmind Technologies    (Koray Kavukcuoglu)
Copyright (c) 2011-2012 NEC Laboratories America (Koray Kavukcuoglu)
Copyright (c) 2011-2013 NYU                      (Clement Farabet)
Copyright (c) 2006-2010 NEC Laboratories America (Ronan Collobert, Leon Bottou, Iain Melvin, Jason Weston)
Copyright (c) 2006      Idiap Research Institute (Samy Bengio)
Copyright (c) 2001-2004 Idiap Research Institute (Ronan Collobert, Samy Bengio, Johnny Mariethoz)
Copyright (c) 2015      Google Inc.
Copyright (c) 2015      Yangqing Jia
Copyright (c) 2013-2016 The Caffe contributors
All rights reserved.

Various files include modifications (c) NVIDIA CORPORATION & AFFILIATES.  All rights reserved.

This container image and its contents are governed by the NVIDIA Deep Learning Container License.
By pulling and using the container, you accept the terms and conditions of this license:
https://developer.nvidia.com/ngc/nvidia-deep-learning-container-license

root@a08973389041:/app# python3 run.py --source live
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/app/app.py", line 57, in video_feed
    video = Process(os.path.abspath('./temp'),
  File "/app/process.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.recognizer = Predictor(file=False, label=True)
  File "/app/scripts/FaceRecognition.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.model = SingleShotLearningFR(pretrained=True)
  File "/app/scripts/FRMethods/SingleShotLearningFR.py", line 29, in __init__
    super(SingleShotLearningFR, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._register_sharded_tensor_state_dict_hooks_if_available()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 2022, in _register_sharded_tensor_state_dict_hooks_if_available
    self.__class__._register_load_state_dict_pre_hook(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1467, in _register_load_state_dict_pre_hook
    self._load_state_dict_pre_hooks[handle.id] = _WrappedHook(hook, self if with_module else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.module: weakref.ReferenceType["Module"] = weakref.ref(module)
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'weakcallableproxy' object
```

Note : Ask me the details u need, i will add it as edit.
Also mention the possibility of mistakes that causes this error

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, getting the same error message. The workaround which worked for me is to downgrade pytorch-lightning pip package from 1.9.0 to 1.8.6.

Bug is caused by using pytorch package that was compiled from a specific commit, which breaks version comparison code (1.13.0a0+d0d6b1f >= 1.13 does not hold in my case) as described in [PL issue](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/16644#issuecomment-1419758956).

The issue points out another (preferred) workaround - to use stable version of pytorch or wait till [fix](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/pull/16657) is released.